# curve fitting in C#

Tags: c#, curve-fitting

I have a data points x and y in an array. And I know this points goes y=log(nx)+c curve. I want to find the value of n that is fitted to that data points using c#. Are there any library or easy way to find it

thanks...

Answer (score 2):

The [Math.NET](http://devlicio.us/blogs/casey/archive/2009/02/20/ddd-the-repository-pattern.aspx) library has what you need, including interpolation.

Comment: Math.NET seems to be a good answer, but the link seems to point to an irrelevant resource ("DDD: The Repository Pattern"). Here's a better one: http://christoph.ruegg.name/blog/linear-regression-mathnet-numerics.html

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Iridium library for .net.